# IntelliJ not updating Glassfish Deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish, updates

IntelliJ is acting odd with its redeployment settings.

In the "updating applications" tab it has on the bottom for debugging:

[image: THIS RIGHT HERE],

I have tried to use all of the update options in order to update my application (update classes, update classes resources, restart), and NONE work to update my server. I have even closed and rebooted IntelliJ and the updates still don't appear.

The update is a simple alert message that is triggered when the index.html is loaded. It works when I load the html manually, but when I run the server, it does not alert, meaning it is still using a previous iteration of my server? This is really frustrating as I can't see any of my changes and don't know how to fix my server.

I am using the latest Glassfish server and latest IntelliJ IDE. It does update my resources EVENTUALLY, but not through some defined pattern as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the copy of my answer from [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345095/specifics-on-how-glassfish-server-is-run-with-intellij-debugger). I would suggest to close this one and to continue discussion in single thread (if still needed).

The expected sequence is as follows:

1. make a change to a resource
2. update the application on the server with the mentioned 'Update <> application' action: 'Update resource' choice should be enough for an exploded application, redeploy/restart may be needed for archive artifact
3. reload (refresh) the page, that uses the resource in browser

I suspect you're missing the last (3) step. Please note, step (2) only updates the resource on the server, and to see a change in browser (on client) you should reload the corresponding resources from server by refreshing the page manually.

Hope that helps,