# 'Use custom context root' does not work for deployment EAR application to GlassFish in IntelliJ IDEA Server Run Configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee, ear, glassfish-4.1, intellij-idea-2018, enterprise-architecture

I changed the context root for the ear artifact. I opened the 'Deployment' tab of the Server Run Configuration, check 'Use custom context root' and enter the desired value into the field: /T4000_Enterprise

But the Application Name in GlassFish stayed equal to the name of Output directory(or the Package name): T4000_Enterprise-3.08.HEAD-SNAPSHOT
[image]
What is wrong? Can I fix it?

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13)
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 EAP (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.3569.1, built on July 3, 2018
JRE/JDK: 1.8.0_152-release-1226-b7 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Answer (score 0):

It is an Idea 2018.2 error. I have opened the issue description here: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196097
I just have noted that the issue was resolved! :)
Fix versions    2018.3
State   Submitted → Fixed